# tensorflow object detection eval error

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

When I use a model to check the mAP on test datasets, I got the following error:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /home/aurora/workspaces/PycharmProjects/tensorflow/tensorflow_object_detection/outputs/model.ckpt-278075
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /home/aurora/workspaces/PycharmProjects/tensorflow/tensorflow_object_detection/outputs/model.ckpt-278075
WARNING:root:The following classes have no ground truth examples: 0
/home/aurora/workspaces/PycharmProjects/tensorflow/tensorflow_object_detection/object_detection/utils/metrics.py:145:                RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
num_images_correctly_detected_per_class / num_gt_imgs_per_class)
```

I examined test.tfrecords, and every image have ground-truth bounding-boxes.
How could I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: By the way, what is the mAP here? Thanks.

Comment: I used the default setting. I think it is `pascal_voc_metrics`.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error and I was stuck for many days on that error.
I could resolve that error by editing my label.pbtxt file. Could you show your label(.pbtxt) file?
My label file was :(containing 3 labels)

```
item {
  id: 1
  name: 'tree'

  id: 2
  name: 'water body'

  id: 3
  name: 'building'
}
```

Then I changed that to :

```
item {
  id: 1
  name: 'tree'
     }

item {
  id: 2
  name: 'water body'
     }

item {
  id: 3
  name: 'building'
     }
```

This worked in my case. Have a look at your .pbtxt file which you reference to in the config file of your model.